# XSLT 2.0 key function returning duplicate node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Source XML : Below XML is the source for the XSLT transformation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<process xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AFR01/Test_Email/BPELProcess1">
  <input>
    <att1>att11</att1>
    <att2>att22</att2>
    <att3>
      <att1>att13</att1>
      <att2>att24</att2>
      <att3>att35</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att16</att1>
      <att2>att27</att2>
      <att3>att38</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att19</att1>
      <att2>att210</att2>
      <att3>att311</att3>
    </att3>
  </input>
   <input>
    <att1>att11</att1>
    <att2>att22</att2>
    <att3>
      <att1>att13</att1>
      <att2>att24</att2>
      <att3>att35</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att16</att1>
      <att2>att27</att2>
      <att3>att38</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att19</att1>
      <att2>att210</att2>
      <att3>att311</att3>
    </att3>
  </input>
    <input>
    <att1>att11</att1>
    <att2>att22</att2>
    <att3>
      <att1>att13</att1>
      <att2>att24</att2>
      <att3>att35</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att16</att1>
      <att2>att27</att2>
      <att3>att38</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att19</att1>
      <att2>att210</att2>
      <att3>att311</att3>
    </att3>
  </input>
  <input>
    <att1>att21</att1>
    <att2>att23</att2>
    <att3>
      <att1>att13</att1>
      <att2>att24</att2>
      <att3>att35</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att16</att1>
      <att2>att27</att2>
      <att3>att38</att3>
    </att3>
    <att3>
      <att1>att19</att1>
      <att2>att210</att2>
      <att3>att311</att3>
    </att3>
  </input>
</process>
```

XSL Transformation 2.0: Below is the XSL transformation source code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:funcLog="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/fahretail.integrations.common.XSLTLogMessageCall"
                xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction"
                xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
                xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
                xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
                xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator"
                xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas"
                xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
                xmlns:oraxsl="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java"
                xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AFR01/Test_Email/BPELProcess1"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:funcReplace="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/fahretail.integrations.common.XSLTStringReplaceXpathFunction"
                xmlns:funcXSL="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/fahretail.integrations.fusion.utility.SOAConvertDateTimeStamp"
                xmlns:func="http://www.fahretail.com/integrations/common/CustomXpathfunctions"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsd oracle-xsl-mapper xsi xsl ns0 funcLog mhdr oraext xp20 xref socket dvm oraxsl funcReplace funcXSL func"
                xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
                xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
    <!--SPECIFICATION OF MAP SOURCES AND TARGETS, DO NOT MODIFY.-->
    <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:source type="WSDL">
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../WSDLs/BPELProcess1.wsdl"/>
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="process"
                                       namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AFR01/Test_Email/BPELProcess1"/>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:source>
    </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapSources>
    <oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
      <oracle-xsl-mapper:target type="WSDL">
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:schema location="../WSDLs/BPELProcess1.wsdl"/>
        <oracle-xsl-mapper:rootElement name="processResponse"
                                       namespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AFR01/Test_Email/BPELProcess1"/>
      </oracle-xsl-mapper:target>
    </oracle-xsl-mapper:mapTargets>
    <!--GENERATED BY ORACLE XSL MAPPER 12.2.1.3.0(XSLT Build 170820.1700.2557) AT [FRI NOV 27 10:09:37 IST 2020].-->
  </oracle-xsl-mapper:schema>
  <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
  <xsl:key name="test01" match="ns0:input" use="ns0:att1"/>
  <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
  <xsl:key name="test02" match="ns0:input" use="ns0:att2"/>
  <!--User Editing allowed BELOW this line - DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
  <xsl:key name="test03" match="ns0:att3" use="ns0:att1"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns0:processResponse>
      <ns0:input>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('test01', 'att11')/key('test02', 'att22')">
          <ns0:att1>
            <xsl:value-of select="ns0:att2"/>
          </ns0:att1>
          <xsl:for-each select="key('test03', 'att13')">
            <ns0:att3>
              <ns0:att1>
                <xsl:value-of select="ns0:att1"/>
              </ns0:att1>
            </ns0:att3>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </ns0:input>
    </ns0:processResponse>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: Below is the oputput XML transformed

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:processResponse xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AFR01/Test_Email/BPELProcess1">
   <ns0:input>
      <ns0:att1>att22</ns0:att1>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att1>att22</ns0:att1>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att1>att22</ns0:att1>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
   </ns0:input>
</ns0:processResponse>
```

Expected output: Below is the expected XML transformation i'm looking for

```
<?xml version = '1.0' encoding = 'UTF-8'?>
<ns0:processResponse xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/AFR01/Test_Email/BPELProcess1">
   <ns0:input>
      <ns0:att1>att22</ns0:att1>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
     
      <ns0:att1>att22</ns0:att1>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
     
      <ns0:att1>att22</ns0:att1>
      <ns0:att3>
         <ns0:att1>att13</ns0:att1>
      </ns0:att3>
   
   </ns0:input>
</ns0:processResponse>
```

I'm not expecting duplicate nodes in second for loop while transforming.
I'm using XSLT 2.0 here.

Comment: You are getting duplicate nodes because your instruction `<xsl:for-each select="key('test03', 'att13')">` processes **all** `att3` elements with a `att1` child whose value is `"att13"` **in the entire XML document, regardless of the current context**. There is probably a much simpler way to accomplish your goal - but I am not entirely sure what that is. A simpler and less confusing example, with a clear statement of the logic that needs to applied would be helpful.

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you can reduce the problem to something that we can see at a glance without scrolling. By making us scroll through a pageful of namespace declarations that aren't even used, you are losing half your readers.