# XSLT 2.0 remove elements based on condition and copy rest within for-each-group

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I'm looking to copy the input XML as is and remove redundant records having same "FULFILMENT_LINE_ID" value and also remove "ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF", "RELATIONSHIP_TYPE" for the redundant node

input XML like below

```
<InputParameters xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://www.testing.com/learning" >
    <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534646</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000365</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528224</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000365-1002-M</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>Component Of</nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528224</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534647</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000328</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>Component Of</nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528229</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534648</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000327</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>Component Of</nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528239</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
    </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
</InputParameters>
```

Expected output is below:

```
<InputParameters xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://www.testing.com/learning" >
    <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000365-1002-M</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528224</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534647</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000328</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>Component Of</nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528229</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534648</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000327</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>
            <nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>100000006534645</nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF>
            <nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>Component Of</nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE>
            <nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>300000008528239</nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID>
            <nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>3</nstrgmpr:IB_RECORD_COUNT>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM>
    </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
</InputParameters>
```

XSLT is below I'm using

```
    <!--User Editing Not Allowed for Sections: oracle-xsl-mapper:schema, top level xsl:params, version attribute of the stylesheet element. GENERATED BY OIC MAPPER, DO NOT DELETE THIS LINE-->
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/taskLayer/activity/model/view/" xmlns:nsmpr0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/service/" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/taskLayer/model/" xmlns:flt="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/service/fault" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:errors="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/errors/" xmlns:ns0="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/svc/types/" xmlns:sdoXML="commonj.sdo/xml" xmlns:sdoJava="commonj.sdo/java" xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension" xmlns:tns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:oracle-xsl-mapper="http://www.oracle.com/xsl/mapper/schemas" xmlns:nsmpr1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/flex/scm/doo/processOrder/pjcDff/" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:nstrgdfl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:nssrcmpr="http://xmlns.oracle.com/types/GetFulfillmentRequest_OM_Trigger/1611909117418/InboundSOAPRequestDocument" xmlns:sdo="commonj.sdo" xmlns:nsmpr2="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/taskLayer/activity/model/" xmlns:nsmpr3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/atpdatabase/SHARE_Procedure_Invoke_REQUEST" xmlns:nssrcdfl="http://xmlns.oracle.com/procmon" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/taskLayer/externalInterfaceLayer/DooTaskExternalInterfaceVirtualPartnersComposite/FulfillmentRequest" xmlns:nsmpr4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/model/" xmlns:nstrgmpr="http://www.testing.com/learning" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:nsmpr5="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/fulfillLineContextsB/" xmlns:ignore01="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java" xmlns:nsmpr6="http://xmlns.oracle.com/oxp/service/PublicReportService" xmlns:nsmpr7="http://xmlns.oracle.com/types/AssetReportBIPBILLTO_SCM_Invoke02/1623285961773/OutboundSOAPRequestDocument" xmlns:nsmpr8="http://xmlns.oracle.com/types/AssetReportBIP_SCM_Invoke01/1623285741394/OutboundSOAPRequestDocument" xmlns:nsmpr9="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/GetAssetDetails_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr10="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/GetAssetRelationshipDetail_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr11="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_GetHubOrganization_CX_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr12="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderBillToCustomer_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr13="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderForOrderHub_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr14="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderShipToCustomer_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr15="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Read_BIPBILLTOReport_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr16="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Read_BIPSHIPTOReport_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr17="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Write_BIPBILLTOReport_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr18="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Write_BIPSHIPTOReport_REQUEST/types" xmlns:nsmpr19="http://www.oracle.com/2014/03/ic/integration/metadata" xmlns:ns97="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Write_BIPBILLTOReport_REQUEST" xmlns:nxsd="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/nxsd" xmlns:ns70="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/GetAssetRelationshipDetail_SCM_Invoke/types" xmlns:ns69="http://xml.oracle.com/types/REST/GetAssetRelationshipDetail_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST" xmlns:ns72="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/Invoke_GetHubOrganization_CX" xmlns:ns75="http://xml.oracle.com/types/REST/Invoke_GetHubOrganization_CX_REQUEST" xmlns:ns78="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderBillToCustomer_REQUEST/RESTOUTRES" xmlns:ns80="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderBillToCustomer/types" xmlns:ns55="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/salesCreditCategories/" xmlns:ns81="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderBillToCustomer_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns100="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/opaque/" xmlns:ns89="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderShipToCustomer" xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/com.bea.wli.sb.functions.dvm.DVMFunctions" xmlns:ns71="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_GetHubOrganization_CX_REQUEST/RESTOUTRES" xmlns:ns49="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/priceAdjustmentCategories/" xmlns:ns67="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/GetAssetRelationshipDetail_SCM_Invoke" xmlns:ns52="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/lotSerialNumberCategories/" xmlns:orajs2="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1530914355" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:orajs3="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1846217501" xmlns:ns73="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_GetHubOrganization_CX_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns62="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/GetAssetDetails_SCM_Invoke/types" xmlns:ns3="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue" xmlns:ns54="http://xmlns.oracle.com/ics/tracking/ics_tracking_context.xsd" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns96="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Read_BIPSHIPTOReport_REQUEST" xmlns:ns101="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Write_BIPSHIPTOReport_REQUEST" xmlns:ns47="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/fulfillLineDetailCategories/" xmlns:ns58="http://xml.oracle.com/types/REST/GetAssetDetails_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST" xmlns:ns48="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/headerCategories/" xmlns:ns68="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/GetAssetRelationshipDetail_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns98="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/ics/file/v1/types" xmlns:ns85="http://xml.oracle.com/types/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderForOrderHub_REQUEST" xmlns:ns51="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/taskLayer/activity/flex/activityCategories/" xmlns:ns86="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderForOrderHub/types" xmlns:ns84="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderForOrderHub_REQUEST" xmlns:ns59="http://xml.oracle.com/adapters/extension" xmlns:ns65="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/GetAssetRelationshipDetail_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST/RESTOUTRES" xmlns:ns76="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderBillToCustomer" xmlns:ns92="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderShipToCustomer_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns88="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderShipToCustomer_REQUEST/RESTOUTRES" xmlns:ns83="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderForOrderHub" xmlns:ns95="http://TargetNamespace.com/fileReference/StageFile_Read_BIPSHIPTOReport" xmlns:ns94="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/stagefile/StageFile_Read_BIPBILLTOReport_REQUEST" xmlns:orajs4="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1905736912" xmlns:connprop="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties" xmlns:ns50="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/paymentCategories/" xmlns:ns99="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/staging/write" xmlns:ns60="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/generic/rest/fault/REST/GetAssetDetails_SCM_Invoke" xmlns:ns63="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/GetAssetDetails_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns64="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/GetAssetDetails_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST/RESTOUTRES" xmlns:ns53="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apps/scm/doo/processOrder/flex/fulfillLineCategories/" xmlns:ns74="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_GetHubOrganization_CX/types" xmlns:orajs0="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath86288" xmlns:ns79="http://xml.oracle.com/types/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderBillToCustomer_REQUEST" xmlns:ns5="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/com.bea.wli.sb.resources.icsxpathfunctions.ICSInstanceTrackingFunctions" xmlns:ns90="http://xml.oracle.com/types/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderShipToCustomer_REQUEST" xmlns:ns91="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderShipToCustomer/types" xmlns:orajs1="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.JsExecutor_xpath1677201779" xmlns:ns87="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderForOrderHub_REQUEST/RESTOUTREQ" xmlns:ns82="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/connectivityproperties/REST/Invoke_SCM_GetSalesOrderForOrderHub_REQUEST/RESTOUTRES" xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/GetAssetDetails_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST" xmlns:ns93="http://TargetNamespace.com/fileReference/StageFile_Read_BIPBILLTOReport" xmlns:nsmpr20="http://xmlns.oracle.com/cloud/adapter/REST/GetSpokeSystemItems_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST/types" version="2.0" xml:id="id_1" exclude-result-prefixes=" ns1 nsmpr0 oraext ns2 xsd errors ns0 sdoXML sdoJava ora tns oracle-xsl-mapper nsmpr1 fn xsl xp20 nssrcmpr sdo nsmpr2 nssrcdfl client nsmpr4 xsi nsmpr5 ignore01" ignore01:ignorexmlids="true">
    <xsl:param name="gSHARE_Input_Param" xml:id="id_131"/>
    <xsl:param name="AssetReportBIP_SCM_Invoke01" xml:id="id_172"/>
    <xsl:param name="AssetReportBIP_SCM_Invoke01_REQUEST" xml:id="id_173"/>
    <xsl:param name="GetSpokeSystemItems_SCM_Invoke" xml:id="id_174"/>
    <xsl:param name="GetSpokeSystemItems_SCM_Invoke_REQUEST" xml:id="id_175"/>
    <xsl:param name="StageFile_Read_BIPSHIPTOReport" xml:id="id_176"/>
    <xsl:param name="StageFile_Write_BIPSHIPTOReport" xml:id="id_177"/>
    <xsl:param name="StageFile_Write_BIPSHIPTOReport_REQUEST" xml:id="id_178"/>
    <xsl:param name="gAssetAPIResponse" xml:id="id_179"/>
    <xsl:param name="gTempAssetRelationship" xml:id="id_180"/>
    <xsl:param name="self" xml:id="id_181"/>
    <xsl:param name="tracking_var_1" xml:id="id_182"/>
    <xsl:param name="tracking_var_2" xml:id="id_183"/>
    <xsl:param name="tracking_var_3" xml:id="id_184"/>
    <xsl:param name="vCheckAssetFlag" xml:id="id_185"/>
    <xsl:param name="vFulfilmentLineID" xml:id="id_186"/>
    <xsl:param name="vGUID_BILLTO" xml:id="id_187"/>
    <xsl:param name="vGUID_SHIPTO" xml:id="id_188"/>
    <xsl:param name="vIntegrationCode" xml:id="id_189"/>
    <xsl:param name="vOIC_Virtual_StagingDir" xml:id="id_190"/>
    <xsl:param name="vRelationshipCount" xml:id="id_191"/>
    <xsl:param name="vStatus" xml:id="id_192"/>
    <xsl:param name="vStatusDescription" xml:id="id_193"/>
    <xsl:template match="/" xml:id="id_11">
        <nstrgmpr:InputParameters xml:id="id_12">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="nstrgmpr:InputParameters/*"/>
        </nstrgmpr:InputParameters>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG">
        <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM[nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF != '']" group-by="nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="count(current-group()) &gt; 1">
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[2]/nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE"/>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[2]/nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF"/>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE"/>
    <xsl:template match="nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With above XSLT logic I'm getting same input XML in output

I have updated my input and xslt in below editor

```
https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXn/4
```

Comment: Please post code we can run *as is* without adding/modifying anything. That means a **complete** stylesheet (including namespace declarations) and an input that produces the claimed output (yours does not).

Comment: In general, if you want your templates to take effect, you need to use `xsl:apply-templates`, not `xsl:copy-of`.

Comment: I have added entire XSLT stylesheet

Comment: And the output is not what you claim: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXn

Comment: Output I'm getting same like input without any change

Comment: Not true - see the link above.

Comment: I suggest ([once again!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031306/xslt-2-0-key-function-returning-duplicate-node#comment114971654_65031306)) you reduce your example to the minimum required to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I have updated the xsl in below, please check -> https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXn/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXn/5 doing

```
   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG">
          <nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG_ITEM[nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_INSTANCE_REF != '']" group-by="nstrgmpr:FULFILMENT_LINE_ID">
                      <xsl:copy-of select="." copy-namespaces="no"/>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
          </nstrgmpr:P_INSTALL_BASE_STG>
    </xsl:template>
```

might get you closer, it is hard to tell, with all the namespaces, longish element names and longish data whether that is already the result you want. And I guess in your real application all those namespaces declared are used elsewhere.

If you want your other templates to delete certain elements to be applied you need to push your nodes to them so e.g. `<xsl:apply-templates select="if (current-group()[2]) then current-group()[2] else ." />` will push the first and single item of single item groups and the second item of more than one item groups to your templates.

Comment: Thank You. But i want to fetch the second element i.e.  
<nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000365-1002-M</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>  instead of <nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>9W0000365</nstrgmpr:ITEM_NUMBER>.  And also as i mentioned i want to remove the below elements only in first node using below         <xsl:template match="nstrgmpr:RELATIONSHIP_TYPE"/>
        <xsl:template match="nstrgmpr:ORIG_SYS_PARENT_INSTANCE_REF"/>

Comment: As you were already told in a comment, if you want to have your templates applied use apply-templates, not copy-of.  So https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rXn/6 might be another step although don't expect anyone to be able to tell with that data which element and data you want to select and which one you want to delete, cut your samples to a minimum to demonstrate the issue.